# For Testflight, must devices be registered with the Apple portal even for Enterprise distribution?

Tags: ios, testflight

I have an Apple Enterprise account and have created an enterprise build and am assessing whether to host the build myself on a web server or use Testflight.

I'm currently playing around with Testflight and have uploaded a build and am trying to install into onto devices.

It seems it will not let me install a build onto a device unless that device has been registered with the Apple provisioning portal and the device's UUID included into the provisioning profile.

But isn't this contrary to the point of enterprise builds, where its not necessary for the apps to be registered with the portal?
And it makes it useless for Enterprise apps because even with my enterprise account the portal still says there is a limit of 100 devices that can be registered.

Therefore I must not putting all the pieces together conceptually. I don't understand what's the point of using Testflight for Enterprise apps if the app udid must be registered with the portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you're code signing the application with a Distribution provisioning profile, and have your Distribution certificate installed in your keychain.

It sounds like you're accidentally code signing with a standard Development profile/certificate, which is why your app will only run on that profile's listed devices.